# Designing a LiIon battery pack & charger for a Roomba 400.

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, roomba

I have a device with a 14.4V battery  (a Roomba) and I wish to design a LiIon battery + charging system to replace the existing arrangement.
I would like to charge it with the standard charger that comes with the Roomba. The current battery box will take 8 - 18650 size cells.

My question is will a 4 cell, 14.4 V 4S Li-ion Lithium Battery 18650 Charger Protection Board 15A work to protect the batteries so I can use the standard charger that will provide 20 V to the charger protection board?

I was looking at using this:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/321820489871?_trksid=p2055119.m1438.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Any ideas?  Thanks!

Comment: Questions about products are forbidden http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask http://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 3):

> My question is will a 4 cell, 14.4 V 4S Li-ion Lithium Battery 18650 Charger Protection Board 15A work to protect the batteries so I can use the standard charger that will provide 20 V to the charger protection board?

Choose one - listed with highest probability first:

- No
- Not really
- Not very well.
  Expect very short battery life.
  Or very very short.
- Maybe for a while
- Maybe

A protection board is intended to be used to protect the cells against extremes and excesses. It is not intended to be a charger UNLESS that functionality is specifically included.
The example board includes the word "charger" in the description in some places and not in others. The specifications do not indicate that charging is a major intention.

Charger ICs and charging PCBs and whole chargers, targeted at 4S charging are 'common enough'. Design or use one.

A protection circuit may not prevent overvoltage when charging, probably-won't terminate charging  when Ichg falls to a preset fraction of Ichg_max, probably does not limit Ichg to a safe level and probably allows discharge to voltages which are damaging in repeated use.